# Appending a dynamic div in another previously dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to add a div within another div, both of which are dynamically created. I'm honestly unsure why it's not adding it in within the `newDiv`

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.dropdown = function(){

        return this.each(function(){

            //Gather information
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            //Get the original selection and keep it as a reference
            var original = $(this);

            //Create a new div with a predefined class and taking the ID from the original HTML.
            var newDiv = $("<div id='"+id+"' class='dropDownJs' />");

            //Remove the id from the original HTML
            original.removeAttr("id");

            //Encapsulate the original dropdown with a new parent div
            original.wrap(newDiv);

            //Create children divs within the parent div for each option within the selection HTML.
            original.children().each(function(){

                //Grab crucial values from the original.
                //The value of the option
                var val = $(this).val();

                //The text from the option (label)
                var text = $(this).text();


                //Child divs to create
                var child = $("<div class='dropDownJsChild'></div>");

                newDiv.append(child);

            });

        });
    }
}(jQuery))
```

For all intensive purposes, this jQuery is manipulating this HTML snippet

```
<select id="test" class="dropdown">
    <option value="something1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="something2">Something 2</option>
    <option value="something3">Something 3</option>
</select>
```

To clarify further:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdown").dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the `newDiv.add(child)` isn't working, and I've also tried doing `newDiv.append(child)` which has also failed.

Comment: it does not work because on `original.wrap(newDiv);` youre having divs with the same ID which is prohibited and false and very evil

Comment: also, try `var child = $("<div class='dropDownJsChild'></div>");`

Comment: But that's why I remove the attribute. What does that have to do with it not working?

Comment: as i guessed youre trying to create invalid html, select tags may only have optgroup or option tags as children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method of `original` element:

```
var child = $("<div class='dropDownJsChild' />");
original.after(child);
```

And the reason why you can't use `newDiv` to append new elements is obvious from documentation for [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> A copy of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements.

So wrapping element is not *original* element anymore, it's a copy of it and does not represend the original node.

Comment: Huzzah! You're a Godsend. Thanks for actually helping me out! It worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As it turns out, the OP is trying to create invalid HTML structures, wrapping option tags inside div tags or whatever, so lets close this

---

Dont create a div with the same id as an existing one and wrap them like here: `original.wrap(newDiv);` remove the id before this

Secondly, youre using the add function which is not what you are looking for, rather use append:

`newDiv.append(child);`

the add function extends the jquery object newDiv by the child. append moves elements into others within the DOM.

Comment: I had already said... I've tried using the append method, which had failed.

Comment: maybe use `var child = $("<div class='dropDownJsChild'></div>");` ?

Comment: does original even have child elements? because youre wrapping the new div around the original div

Comment: It does, it is a, in HTML, the `<options>` tag.

Comment: you cant wrap an options element inside a div, or put an a tag inside option tags

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. I'm not wrapping an options tag around a div. It's the opposite. The div is wrapping around the options tag.

Comment: yep and that is wrong, please read some stuff about valid html regarding selects

Comment: What on earth... You're closing this because it's off topic? I'm not wrapping options tags around a div. I'm wrapping a div around the options tag... Why don't you look at my code again....

Comment: @Majed Why on the earth You are trying to do that?

Comment: For gods sake you may not wrap divs around options, its not valid HTML! God gave us google! And its off topic because youre trying to achieve something that is symantically wrong and really basic HTML knowledge

Comment: Sorry, I meant the selection. LOOK AT THE CODE! It shows you EVERYTHING.

Comment: But you said you are trying to wrap a div around option tags, please dont use caps, this is not reddit. get your code and question together before you bother people!

Comment: I meant the selection tag.

Comment: `I'm attempting to add a div within another div` still is the first words of this question, sersiously...

Comment: I added more code to clarify further what I was trying to do.

Comment: What you mean and what you write are different things, arent they?

Comment: First wrapping a div around the `<select>`. Then, I'm trying to add a `<div>` inside that `<div>` I created that wrapped around the selection.

Comment: rather "how to add a div after by select element", from the code you provided earlier it was not clear at all. had enough of this :*

Comment: That's fine, the other guy helped a lot. His suggestion worked great.